# Parsing Oracle Date to C# datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, type-conversion

I need to `Parse` the following string as a `DateTime` in **c#**:

```
"22-FEB-21 09.52.41.256898000 AM"
```

I've tried the following but it *throws exception*:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(
  "22-FEB-21 09.52.41.256898000 AM",
  "DD-MON-YY HH.mm.ss.ff AM", 
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The **exception** being thrown is

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Why only two ff's for milliseconds?

Comment: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: isnt it MMM instead of MON

Comment: `d-MMM-yy h.m.s.ffffff'000' tt`

Comment: this works --- Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("22-FEB-21 09.52.41.256898 AM","dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.ffffff tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

Comment: and this - Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("22-FEB-21 09.52.41.256898000 AM","dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.ffffff000 tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

Comment: How are you getting the date out of Oracle? Because ADO.Net should be returning a DateTime object in the first place, which means you likely have code (possibly in a library) doing extra work to convert this to a string, which you now have to convert _back_ to a DateTime... And thanks to localization issues this is some of the most expensive code in your data layer, which you are now running _twice_ more often than you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
d-MMM-yy h.m.s.ffffff'000' tt
```

*format string*. I.e.

```
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(
  "22-FEB-21 09.52.41.256898000 AM", 
  "d-MMM-yy h.m.s.ffffff'000' tt", 
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Format explained:

```
 d      - day in one ore two digit format
 MMM    - month (abbreviation)
 yy     - year (two digits)
 h      - hour 1..12 or 01..12
 m      - minutes 00..59 or 0..59
 s      - seconds 00..59 or 0..59
 ffffff - fraction of seconds
'000'   - 000
 tt     - AM or PM
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems with your date string.
First, are you sure you are getting 9 decimal places? Since Oracle only supports 6 decimals of precision, maybe you can do something on the query side to remove those?

Also your format string has some problems.

1. It should be MMM not MON for the month
2. It should be hh since you are using a 12 hour clock standard (AM/PM) and not 24 hours.

Then you need to fix your fractional seconds, and use a string match for the last two zeros.
Your format string ends up to be:

```
"d-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.fffffff'00' tt"
```

So to test it, you can run this:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(
   "22-FEB-21 09.52.41.258998000 AM",
   "d-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.fffffff'00' tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Be careful with `dd`: we can't be sure that **2nd Feb** will be with leading zero: `02-FEB-21 09.52.41.258998000 AM` and not `2-FEB-21 09.52.41.258998000 AM`. Please, put `d` instead of `dd` to be on the *safe side*